# I have to send an email through an API Rest, should I wait to return the result of the mailing?

Tags: rest, email, endpoint

In an endpoint where an email is sent through an API Rest, for example, user is created and I need to send email for mail verification.

Should I wait for the mailing to finish and get the result to return if the email has been sent successfully?

This way, sometimes, the enpoint's response exceeded of 2000 ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what sort of service you're using but 2 secs for sending out an email is taking too long.

In such cases, the best thing would be to make an async call to this endpoint and use a Database to update once the email has been sent out.